# llvm: get function from a "call" instruction

Tags: llvm

Consider the llvm instruction:

```
%call3 = call i32 @square(i32 %1)
```

Is it possible to extract the pointer to the "square" function ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 14):

There is [`Function* CallInst::getCalledFunction() const`](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1CallInst.html#a0bcd4131e1a1d92215f5385b4e16cd2e) method.